# Visual FFMPEG Crop?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

Is there a way to get a 'preview' of an ffmepg command to see how the current crop settings would look on an exported video? If not I'll use handbreak as it has a visual preview window when cropping which is great, I'd love to stay within ffmpeg though.

Answer (score 3):

`ffplay` alone can be used for previewing:

```
ffplay -vf crop=100:100:12:34 input.mp4
```

This will quickly show a preview of your filtering, but not any encoding artifacts that may be present once you use `ffmpeg`.

[Static `ffplay` binaries for OS X](http://www.evermeet.cx/ffplay/) are available or you can follow a [compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX).